# Unable to make timer loop after hitting zero

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, timer

I'm working on a timer that counts down from a set number and when it reaches zero, it should rest back and start again.

```cs
private int timer;
public int duration;

private bool timerRunning = true;

void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine("TimeDown");

    timer = duration;
}

void Update()
{

    if (timer <= 0f)
    {
        timer = duration;

        Debug.Log("Timer Reset");

        timerRunning = false;

    }

    if (timerRunning == false)
    {
        StartCoroutine("TimeDown");

        timerRunning = true;
    }


    Debug.Log("Timer: " +timer);
}

IEnumerator TimeDown()
{
    while (true)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        timer--;
    }
}
```

The issue I am getting is getting the timer to loop. Once it sends the "Timer Reset" message it no longer runs the timer anymore.

Comment: because you never reset timer to duration... so it stays at 0

Comment: @BugFinder doesn't it do that at the start of the `if (timer <= 0f)` block?

Comment: Does it work if you remove the redundant `StartCoroutine` call in `Update`? You don't want to have multiple `TimeDown` coroutines running in pseudo-parallel.

Comment: @Tom I rejected your edit to Fredrik's answer because it should be its own answer. You can answer your own question with a solution that worked for you if the other answer is completely different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest massively simplifying your logic to something like this:

```
private int timer;
public int duration;

void Start()
{
    timer = duration;
    StartCoroutine(TimeDown());
}

void Update()
{
    // Nothing is needed each frame so Update() should be removed
}

IEnumerator TimeDown()
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (timer <= 0)
            timer = duration;

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);

        timer--;
        Debug.Log("Timer: " + timer);
    }
}
```

And also make sure that `duration` is set in the inspector.